# How to use `otel_resource_detector` from OpenTelemetry in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, open-telemetry

I'm an Erlang/Elixir noob and I'm doing a research on how to use the `otel_resource_detector` in Elixir.
I've managed to get this working in Erlang some time ago, but I'm struggling to get things right in Elixir.
This is what I have in Erlang:

```
-module(extra_metadata).
-behaviour(otel_resource_detector).
-export([get_resource/1]).

get_resource(_) ->
    Resource1 = otel_resource:create(otel_resource_app_env:parse(get_metadata("/data/extrametadata.properties")), []),
    {ok, HiddenMetadataFile} = file:read_file("/data/hiddenpath.properties"),
    Resource2 = otel_resource:create(otel_resource_app_env:parse(get_metadata(HiddenMetadataFile)), []),
    otel_resource:merge(Resource1, Resource2).

get_metadata(FileName) ->
try
    {ok, MetadataFile} = file:read_file(FileName),
    Lines = binary:split(MetadataFile, <<"\n">>, [trim, global]),
    make_tuples(Lines, [])
catch _:_ -> "Extra Metadata not found"
end.

make_tuples([Line|Lines], Acc) ->
    [Key, Value] = binary:split(Line, <<"=">>),
    make_tuples(Lines, [{Key, Value}|Acc]);
make_tuples([], Acc) -> Acc.
```

Full Erlang app here: https://github.com/julianocosta89/erlang_otel_hello_server/tree/main

I'm trying to make use of the `otel_resource_detector` from OpenTelemetry:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-erlang/blob/37f3cecd9ad2a7b8f3b94c89118585991f0023b1/apps/opentelemetry/src/otel_resource_detector.erl

How would I use that in Elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can easily call [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) modules from [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). The first module would look like

```elixir
defmodule ExtraMetadata do

  @behaviour :otel_resource_detector

  def get_resource(_) do
    resource1 =
      :otel_resource.create(
        :otel_resource_app_env.parse(
          get_metadata("/data/extrametadata.properties")), [])

    {:ok, hidden_metadata_file} =
      File.read("/data/hiddenpath.properties")

    resource2 =
      :otel_resource.create(
        :otel_resource_app_env.parse(
          get_metadata(hidden_metadata_file)), [])

    :otel_resource.merge(resource1, resource2)
  end

  defp get_metadata(file_name) do
    try do
      {:ok, metadata_file} = File.read(file_name)
      lines = :binary.split(metadata_file, <<"\n">>, [:trim, :global])
      make_tuples(lines) 
    catch
      _ -> "Extra Metadata not found"
    end
  end

  # Enum.map/2 would be probably more idiomatic
  defp make_tuples(lines, acc \\ [])
  defp make_tuples([line|lines], acc) do
    [key, value] = :binary.split(line, <<"=">>)
    make_tuples(lines, [{key, value}|cc])
  defp make_tuples([], acc), do: acc
end
```

**NB** I obviously did not check the code above, some glitches might need some additional handling.

Comment: Thx Aleksei, what do u mean by `# Enum.map/2 would be probably more idiomatic`?

Comment: I said that I had not tested it. I fixed the `:global` one above. `Enum.map/2` is more idiomatic in elixir for mapping over plain recursion, what exactly is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet:

```erlang
defmodule ExtraMetadata do

  @behaviour :otel_resource_detector

  def get_resource(_) do
    lines = read_file("/data/extrametadata.properties") |> unwrap_lines
    file_path = read_file("/data/hiddenpath.properties") |> unwrap_lines
    lines2 = read_file(file_path) |> unwrap_lines
    attributes = get_attributes(Enum.concat(lines, lines2))
    :otel_resource.create(attributes)
  end

  defp unwrap_lines({:ok, lines}), do: lines
  defp unwrap_lines({:error, _}), do: []

  defp read_file(file_name) do
    try do
      {:ok, String.split(File.read!(file_name), "\n")}
    rescue
      File.Error ->
        {:error, "File does not exist, safe to continue"}
    end
  end

  defp get_attributes(lines) do
    # Transform each string into a tuple
    Enum.map(lines, fn(line) ->
      if String.length(line) > 0 do
        [key, value] = String.split(line, "=")
        {key, value}
      else
        {:error, "Empty string"}
      end
    end)
  end
end
```

I've also pushed the whole project here: https://github.com/julianocosta89/elixir-hello.